# ADF - Dataflow, using Join to send new values

Tags: azure-data-factory

there are two tables

tbl_1 as a source data

```
ID  | Submission_id
--------------------
1   | A00_1 
2   | A00_2
3   | A00_3
4   | A00_4
5   | A00_5
6   | A00_6
7   | A00_7
```

tbl_2 as destination. In this table, `Submission_id` is unique key.

```
ID  | Submission_id
--------------------
1   | A00_1 
2   | A00_2
3   | A00_3
4   | A00_4
```

`tbl_1` as input value and `tbl_2` as destination (`sink`). Expected result is only `A00_5`, `A00_6` & `A00_7` sent to `tbl_2`. So, this picture below is the `Join`

[image: Join]

for `AlterRow`,
[image: alterRow]

expected ouput
tbl_2

```
ID  | Submission_id
--------------------
1   | A00_1 
2   | A00_2
3   | A00_3
4   | A00_4
5   | A00_5 -->(new)
6   | A00_6 -->(new)
7   | A00_7 -->(new)
```

But, output result from `alterRow` are all `Submission_id`. It should be only not equal comparison that has been stated in the `alter row condition`,
`notEquals(DC__Submission_ID_BigInt, SrcStgDestination@{_Submission_ID})`.

How to solve this problem in Azure DataFlow use 'Join' ?

Comment: Hey @Daleman, in your join transformation, the left stream is `tbl_1` data and right stream is `tbl_2` data. Is this right?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham, yes sir.

Comment: Do you want to achieve your solution only using `join` transformation?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham, YES sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing the same procedure and got the same result (all rows getting inserted). We were able to perform join in the desired way but couldn’t proceed further to get the required output. You can use the approach given below instead, which is achieved using `JOINS`.

- In general, when we want to get records from table1 which are not present in table2, we execute the following query (in sql server).

```
select t1.id,t1.submission_id from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.submission_id = t2.submission_id where t2.submission_id is NULL
```

- In the Dataflow, we were able to achieve the `join` successfully (same procedure as yours). Now instead using `alter row` transformation, I used `filter` transformation (to achieve `t2.submission_id is NULL` condition). I used the following expression (condition) to filter.

```
isNull(d1@submission_id) && isNull(d1@id)
```

[image]

- Now proceed to configure the sink (tbl_2). The preview would show the records as in the below image.

[image]

- Publish and run the `dataflow` activity in your pipeline to get the desired results.

[image]